# OAuth2 spring example sparklr and tonr

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, oauth

I'm trying to get the example of tonr and sparklr working for the framework spring.  I am running into errors with maven.  This is where I'm getting the source code from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth and this is the tutorial I am following: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/wiki/tutorial.  Note: I have successfully made oauth work, but not oauth2.

Here is the first error I get when I run

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

for sparklr.

```
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.springframework.security.oauth:sparklr2:war:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
  spring-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release),
  spring-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
```

This is the error I get for tonr

```
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact: 
  org.springframework.security.oauth:tonr2:war:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  spring-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release),
  spring-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
```

Here are the pom.xml file for sparklr

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sparklr2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>OAuth for Spring Security - Sparklr2 (OAuth 2 Provider Example)</name>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>surefire-it</id>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-tomcat</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <fork>true</fork>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!--skip deploy (this is just a test module) -->
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <!-- Needed for testing (with Spring 4 only), but not at runtime -->
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is the pom.xml file for tonr

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>tonr2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>OAuth for Spring Security - Tonr2 (OAuth 2 Client Example)</name>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>surefire-it</id>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-tomcat</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <fork>true</fork>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!--skip deploy (this is just a test module) -->
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>sparklr2</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>tomcat</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried an older version (1.0.5.RELEASE) but I got a similar error: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security.oauth:sparklr2:war:1.0.5.RELEASE in spring-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)

Comment: Do you need the bleeding edge or could you try switching to the 1.0.X branch in GIT (this is the GA version, or was at one point)? You can then use central Maven repositories.

Answer (score 3):

The first time the project is built, you need to run:

`mvn install -P bootstrap`

The `bootstrap` profile enables some extra repositories.

Comment: Good one! I wonder why the official documentation does not mention this.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you solved the problem, but in any case I had the same error when tried to build in root directory. Try to go directly to `..\samples\oauth2\sparklr\` and run:

> mvn clean install

The same for tonr.

Comment: In my case, I just gave up and used nimbusDS implementation which has a better fit to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was importing the whole [spring-security-oauth2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) project into my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous instructions please use Tomcat 7 server to run by this command:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

instead of

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

Tomcat 6 doesn't start this project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the dependencies tag I had to update the spring-security-oauth2 version to 2.0.8.RELEASE because the SNAPSHOT version was not found in the maven repository. I hope it helps.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```